# An error comes up while exchanging stylesheets

Tags: import, notebooks, options, stylesheet

A notebook contains

```
sty1 = CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], StyleDefinitions];
sty2 = StyleDefinitions /. Options[EvaluationNotebook[]];
If[sty1===sty2,
   Export["001_sty.nb", sty1, "Text"]
]
```

(here, obviously, `If` is present for mere diagnostic goals)

Another one contains

```
sty = Import["001_sty.nb", "Text"];
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], StyleDefinitions -> sty];
```

and this code crashes Mathematica 8.0.1.0 .

A third one contains

```
sty = Import["001_sty.nb", "Text"];
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], StyleDefinitions] = sty;
```

and this time an internal self-test error occurs:

[image]

Probably, there is some flawed code in Kernel or in the FrontEnd: can you, please, supply any suggestion to obtain the aim in an alternate way, bypassing the bug (provided that, there exists one) ?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work as intended:

```
style = CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], StyleDefinitions];
Export["001_sty.nb", style, "Text"];
```

and

```
style = Import["001_sty.nb", "Text"];
SetOptions[
    EvaluationNotebook[], 
    StyleDefinitions -> ToExpression @ style
];
```

Anyway, I think that a crash or an internal self test error, when a simple error message should occur, can be regarded as a bug.